# Which function does Python print use?

Tags: python, string, printing, repr

I've got an object which I print to the terminal, and it looks like this:

```
>>> print b
<p>„De neergang kan een duikvlucht worden.”</p>
```

So I then wondered from which function this the result is. So I tried the following:

```
>>> b.__repr__()
'<lxml.etree._XSLTResultTree object at 0x112c6a980>'
>>> b.__str__()
'\xe2\x80\x9eDe neergang kan een duikvlucht worden.\xe2\x80\x9d</p>'
>>> b.__unicode__()
'u'<p>\u201eDe neergang kan een duikvlucht worden.\u201d</p>'
```

As you can see, neither of these functions displays what the `print` statement shows. I always thought that `print` actually shows the result of either `__repr__()`, `__str__()` or `__unicode__()`, but that is clearly not the case.

So what does `print` actually call?

Comment: It is `__str__`, but when you do just `b.__str__()`, you are in effect doing `print b.__str__().__repr__()`, so it still prints differently.

Comment: Try `print b.__str__()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy enough to check this sort of thing:

```
>>> class C(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        print("repr called")
        return "repr"
    def __str__(self):
        print("str called")
        return "str"
    def __unicode__(self):
        print("unicode called")
        return "unicode"


>>> print C()
str called
str
>>>
```

In fact what happens internally is that `print` (as a function that is, I haven't checked the opcode though I think it is the same) calls PyFile_WriteObject with the Py_PRINT_RAW flag.

> int PyFile_WriteObject(PyObject *obj, PyObject *p, int flags)
>
> Write
>   object obj to file object p. The only supported flag for flags is
>   Py_PRINT_RAW; if given, the str() of the object is written instead of
>   the repr(). Return 0 on success or -1 on failure; the appropriate
>   exception will be set.

Answer (score 1):

> `object.__str__(self)`
>
> Called by `str(object)` and the built-in functions `format()` and `print()` to compute the >'informal' or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value must >be a string object.

This is from python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). So clearly, `print` function will call defined `__str()__`, if you define both `__str()__` and `__repr()__` inside the class. But in the case you just implement `__repr()__`, then `print(object)` shall use `__repr()__`.

Hope this will help.